# Excel: Sum adjacent rows with same value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with the following structure:

```
Timestamp    Name    Value
01/01/2013   X       20
01/01/2013   Y        5
01/01/2013   Y        3
01/01/2013   X        7
01/02/2013   X       15
01/02/2013   X        1  
01/02/2013   Z        8
01/03/2013   Y        1
```

I want to sum the `Value` of adjacent rows with the same `Name` into the first row (keeping the same `Timestamp` and other values on the row, only the `Value` is updated). There can be any number of successive occurrences, I've only put two for the sake of the example. The result of the above example should look like this:

```
Timestamp    Name    Value
01/01/2013   X       20
01/01/2013   Y        8
01/01/2013   X       23
01/02/2013   Z        8
01/03/2013   Y        1
```

Comment: The pivot, just as the consolidate function, sums up all occurrences of X. I only want the adjacent ones summed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub SumAdjacent()
Dim TimeStamp As Date
Dim Name As String
Dim Value As Integer
k = 1
For i = 2 To 80 'range of your data from secound row to 80row(or whatewer you want)
    Value = 0
    TimeStamp = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value
    Name = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value
    Value = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value
    j = i + 1
    'check next row
CheckNextRow:
    If Sheets(1).Cells(j, 2) = Name Then
        Value = Value + Sheets(1).Cells(j, 3).Value
            j = j + 1
            GoTo CheckNextRow ' loop to check every next row value
    Else
        Sheets(2).Cells(k, 1).Value = TimeStamp
        Sheets(2).Cells(k, 2).Value = Name
        Sheets(2).Cells(k, 3).Value = Value
        k = k + 1
                i = j - 1
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I get the following error: "Run-time error '438'". I replaced 80 with 29990 since that is how many rows I have.

Comment: Please change Time stamp to Date type.

Comment: Done. I've also changed sheets to 2 and 3. And now it says Run-time error '9': Script out of range. I've changed the 29990 to 100, but that was not the source.

Comment: @FloIancu try add ActiveSheet.Sheets("nameOfYourSheet").

Comment: I replaced all Sheets(1) with ActiveSheet.Sheets("Sheet2") and so on and now I get Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set. Sorry for bothering you so much, I am completely clueless in VBA!

Comment: @FloIancu It's no problem. We should help together :) Which line make this error? (try press F8 until the error).

Comment: `Name = ActiveSheet.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value` This is the one.

Comment: It's works on my example data. Even without `activesheet`. Make sure that in TimeStamp column you have right cell data type like `DD/MM/YYYY` or `MM/DD/YYYY` and in Value column you have only Integer. If you have long or sth else, you should change this type in VBA.

Comment: It hasn't properly worked for me, but that's maybe because my table is a lot more complicated than that and perhaps I'm missing something. I will try to tweak the code until I get it right. In the meantime I'm going to go ahead and mark your reply as the answer and I thank you for your effort and time, it's much appreciated!

Comment: @FloIancu If you want, I can help you. Pleas paste here sample of your data.